# Reading the oldest version of the Septuagint

Tags: septuagint, resource-request

Will you direct me to the oldest version online or in any library of the Septuagint bible?  In your opinion for some of the ones we have available today, are they accurate in bible study?

Answer (score -1):

The Septuagint is usually a mechanical translation, word for word, of Hebrew, that sounds strange to a koine Greek reader.

Septuaginta Vetus Testamentum Graecum auctoritate Academiae Scienti­arum Gottingensis editum is an academic solution to your question.

Comment: The Septuagint is not " a mechanical translation, word for word, of Hebrew..." , It has many non-word for word phrases in it that explains context.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me there are 100's of Greek versions of the LXX. I question if anyone really knows what the oldest is. One book i have found has many different variations of many old scrolls all compiled in one book (i have seen other books like this... but I am always coming back to this one because it is so thorough). Choose for yourself the reading that seems right. The team that compiled these books is inhuman.

https://archive.org/details/VetusTestamentumGraecumCumVariisLecVol101Genesis

Best Interlinear Greek to English translation I've seen. A good foundation for study. The Greek version seems pretty old. Whoever translated this into English was blessed by the God's. I am unable to buy one, that in my opinion, is better.

https://archive.org/details/InterlinearGreekEnglishSeptuagintOldTestamentPrint/page/n5

Comment: What do you mean by an 'inhuman' 'team' ?